# Difference between processing script editor and Python console when using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I am a PyQGIS beginner.

I'm having trouble to understand the difference between running and writing a Python script from the Python console and from the processing script editor. So far, I've seen that some command are not available in the processing script editor (such as `iface`'s command or print) and in the mean time I can't figure how to run a script issued by the processing editor into the console to have an access to those functions.

For example when I run the default processing script I got those warnings:

[image]

Can you help me to clarify the situation?

Comment: The error shown in your picture is related to pythons indentation sensitivity https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, can you therefore explain why the indentation is not matching between the processing script editor and the python consol ?